# snmpwalk timeout value in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, snmp

Can I set **snmpwalk** time out value ? example:

```
snmpwalk -v2c -c PUBLIC 10.0.0.1  1.3.6.1.4.1.9.2.1.56.0
```

*-t is not working*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-t works fine.
The default value is 1 second before a retry :

```
# time snmpwalk 10.87.55.28 -r 1 -t 5 -v 3 -a SHA -A 1SX52150fbEFfbb -x AES -X e69f85Wxsw121a -l authpriv -u udsdsdsd 1.3.6.1.4.1.674.10893.1.20.140.1
snmpwalk: Timeout

real    0m10.094s
user    0m0.060s
sys     0m0.024s


# time snmpwalk 10.1.2.28 -r 1 -t 20 -v 3 -a SHA -A 1SX52150fbEFfbb -x AES -X e69f85Wxsw121a -l authpriv -u udsdsdsd 1.3.6.1.4.1.674.10893.1.20.140.1
snmpwalk: Timeout

real    0m40.132s
user    0m0.072s
sys     0m0.004s
```

In this example, the first time takes 10 seconds with `-r 1 -t 5` for time out, and the second try takes 40 secondes with `-r 1 -t 20`.

We can deduct of that, snmpwalk send more than one SNMP request and wait for each the `-t` delay.

If your server have a snmp service and the OID doesn't exist, snmpwalk will not wait the delay and return an error. In my example, my server doesn't have a snmp service, it explains the time out.

Comment: I missed RETRY option :) thanks for the pointing @Sorcha

Comment: Is there any option that I can query multiple queries & store it in mysql table. requirement is to get snmp data from 10 different devices and it should query all simultaneously. simultaneous query is required to avoid long wait for each device response (incase a device is down it will still take 1 sec) howto run simultaneous quries for differnt devices?

Comment: @iBBi : you should use a scheduler to manage yours requests and put the results in a databade like nagios icinga2 or centreon. These products offers the possibility to have a database very easy to reuse for a backend process.

Comment: so i guess for every device, i need to add a separate scheduler so that all queries run simultaneously.

Comment: No you will have a server or workstation wjere you were installed the soft which will send yours requests to all devices see the doc nagios or icinga2 for examples